# Tag taskdef cannot find 'org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.xjc.XJC2Task' class

Tags: java, xml, maven, ant

I'm trying to build in Ant but it gives me the error " grammar is not specified at the target tag line.

I've setted all the path correctly and I have all the depencencies in that path.

Here is mi code: I hope you may help me to fix this problem.

```xml
 <target name="regenerate-beans" depends="init">
    <taskdef name="xjc2" classname="org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.xjc.XJC2Task">
        <classpath refid="jrb.compile.classpath" />
    </taskdef>


    <xjc2 destdir="..." binding="..." extension="true">
        <schema dir="..." includes="nGEM.def.xsd" />
        <classpath refid="jrb.compile.classpath" />
    </xjc2>
 </target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the XSD "nGEM.def.xsd" doesn't exist in its `dir` folder. Check if the filepath contains such file.

In other words, "grammar is not specified" could mean `file not found`.

Comment: OK that's exactly what is happening. Thank you very much for the advice. Cheers mate